# DUT unrecognized in modelsim simulation

Tags: vhdl, test-bench

Unfortunately I can't properly debug a code in Modelsim. In fact, during the simulation the DUT is not displayed in the SIM panel (I am attaching a screenshot). So I can just see the waveforms generated by the testbench, but I cannot view the internal signals. It seems that for some reason the TESTER and the DUT are not connected.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Welcome on SO. Without seeing your code there is not much we can do. May I suggest that you [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the signals recursively with the following command:
add wave -recursive /*
Now, if you're not seeing the DUT, you may want to check the waring when the simulation is loading.

- Do you see unbound warnings?
- Did you compile your DUT file?
- Do you find it in the library ?
  Sébastien.